# Could I be held liable for a roommate on a separate lease subleasing without permission?

Tags: texas, sublease

My roommate and I live in a student apartment in Texas. Due to special circumstances, he wants to sublease his half of the apartment to another student for about a month. We've signed separate leases for each unit. Due to extra fees, he doesn't want to report this to management. Could I be held liable if management finds out? How bad of an idea is this?

Comment: What's your goal? To stop him from subleasing? To wet your beak in his deal? Or maybe just to make some troubles for him?

Comment: @Greendrake That seems needlessly hostile. It's clear OP wants none of those things- they want to avoid legal issues with their landlord.

Comment: @Studoku I think it's obvious that, given separate leases, the OP is under no obligation to snitch on his flatmate. Conversely, it is not clear what _"Could I be held liable if management finds out?"_ refers to. Liable for snitching? Or for _not_ snitching? Hence my questions above. No hostility meant at all.

Comment: The only goal was to advise him to any issues that could arise and come to a joint consensus on our comfort level with this maneuver. Since there is shared apartment space, I didn't know to what degree I would be held responsible. I wouldn't want to put him in a compromising situation. I also don't want him to put me in a compromising situation.  @Greendrake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could I be held liable if management finds out?

You might, even if only on grounds of the *implied covenant of good faith and fair dealing*. The matter is otherwise hard to assess without knowing the terms of your lease.

Notwithstanding your mention of "*separate leases for each unit*", the lease might contain language providing joint-and-several liability which might or might not extend to damages the landlord could claim for the roommate's unauthorized sublease. Akin provisions would not be far-fetched. After all, your duty of good faith and fair dealing encompasses the common areas of that same apartment.

> How bad of an idea is this?

Besides the previous point, your non-disclosure might forfeit some of your rights (i.e., pursuant to your lease) in the event that the sub-lessee's actions cause you a loss. That is because your omission deprived the landlord of the opportunity to address the risks associated to unknown sub-lessees.